# Why do browsers display grafics different and how to change that?

Tags: image, google-chrome, firefox, png, color-management

I am working on a website right now. Sadly the **png** logo and as well the background which uses the same colors is displayed on some computers with Firefox in lila. With Chrome the blue looks as expected.

The used monitor also has an effect, but with Chrome everything looks fine.

Where does that issue come from, and how can I fix that?

[Here is my image](http://www.altergear.net/media/tmp/logo.png)

Here you see a photo of my monitor. The lila with firefox (on the left) is visible slightly. The big issue is that the color is used in the background of my website, which looks lila than, with firefox, and the displayed color does not match the other colors in css at my website anymore.

[image]

The above picture is from firefox:
[image]

The above picture is from chrome:
[image]

Comment: "The lila with firefox (on the right) comes out slightly" Slightly what?

Comment: Sorry, at the left, I edited that sentence. Thanks.  I mean that you can see a slight lila touch at the left image. Is that clearified in the question now?

Comment: Not really. I like them not to be displayed different anymore. I hope you at home can observe the issue. Someone told me that firefox-color-management can solve the issue at one computer, but as a webdeveloper I need to solve the issue for all users who display my page: http://www.metalvortex.com/blog/2012/03/16/831.html

Comment: For the one image of the background I changed the image-format to .gif what helped, but for the logo the quality of .gif is too bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox handles images that contain an sRGB profile slightly differently from untagged images and HTML colors, by default.  It has three modes of operation that you can select by going to "about:config", searching for gfx.color_management.mode.  The default is "2".  Change it to "0" (no color management) or "1" (color manage everything) and you'll get a good match.

See the four-year-old bug #621474 at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org and scroll down to comment #49 to see current status of the patch.

Because of these differences (you can't control which setting people use), it's probably best to just remove the iCCP chunk or sRGB chunk from your image.  Browsers will assume the image is in the sRGB colorspace and display it properly against HTML colors.

"pngcheck" says you have iCCP and cHRM chunks:

```
$ pngcheck -v so-logo.png
File: so-logo.png (147985 bytes)
  chunk IHDR at offset 0x0000c, length 13
    506 x 171 image, 32-bit RGB+alpha, non-interlaced
  chunk pHYs at offset 0x00025, length 9: 2835x2835 pixels/meter (72 dpi)
  chunk iCCP at offset 0x0003a, length 2639
    profile name = Photoshop ICC profile, compression method = 0 (deflate)
    compressed profile = 2616 bytes
  chunk cHRM at offset 0x00a95, length 32
    White x = 0.31269 y = 0.32899,  Red x = 0.63999 y = 0.33001
    Green x = 0.3 y = 0.6,  Blue x = 0.15 y = 0.05999
  chunk IDAT at offset 0x00ac1, length 145212
    zlib: deflated, 32K window, maximum compression
  chunk IEND at offset 0x24209, length 0
No errors detected in so-logo.png (6 chunks, 57.2% compression).
```

There are various tools you can use to remove those chunks:

```
pngcrush (also removes the pHYs chunk):
pngcrush -rem alla -force logo.png logo_crushed.png

pngsplit+cat:
pngsplit logo.png
rm logo.png.0003.iCCP
rm logo.png.0004.cHRM
cat logo.png.00*.* > logo_split_cat.png
```

Comment: That sound's like a good hit but does not solve my problem, as long as I can not deliver the prefered setting as a webdeveloper in the css or html code. Because I am developing on the server-side which provides the content, my intention is to deliver content which is displayed for all clients correctly without technical individual changes.

Comment: I tried to remove the color profile with pngcrush, the filesize did not change and the logo-image is still lila in firefox. I also tried to install separate+ for gimp, but I was not able to see changes in gimp after installing the package: gimp-plugin-registry 5.20120621ubuntu3

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pngcrush#Reducing_file_size_by_removing_color-correction_data

Comment: pngcrush should have done it.  Maybe you have an old version (current version is 1.7.85) or forgot to use the -force option.

Comment: Thanks. You helped to solve my problem. Your png-crush command did the job, the one from wikipedia somehow not. Maybe because of the force-option!

Answer (score 1):

PNG files include ICC color profile metadata.  Some browsers ignore this metadata and display the image as if its bits represent an sRGB image.  Other browsers take into account the ICC colorspace and make the appropriate color transformations before outputting to the display.  If the PNG uses the sRGB color profile, it should look the same in all browsers.  However, if your PNG has some other color profile (such as AdobeRGB), then perhaps Firefox is not compensating whereas Chrome is.  In this case, the Firefox image is technically displayed incorrectly, although it will match RGB font colors in your HTML, whereas the Chrome image is displayed "correctly" (i.e. to the creator's original intent for the colors) but will not match the RGB font colors in your HTML (which are specified in sRGB).

Bottom line, check the ICC colorspace of your PNG.

Comment: I already tryed to resave the file with gimp. I will research about the ICC colorspace now.

Comment: sRGB is the default color-profile of GIMP. I also tried saving as jpg which did not fix the issue. Should not resaving with GIMP solve it?
http://digital-photography-school.com/adding-icc-profiles-in-gimp/

Comment: In GIMP you can go to Image->Image Properties->Color Profile to see the image's color profile.  Simply re-saving in GIMP will not necessarily change  color profile.

Comment: Your answers are great (that's why I voted you up) but that's what gimp sais: sRGB IEC61966-2.1
IEC 61966-2.1 Default RGB colour space - sRGB

Comment: @tokam hmm, I don't know then.

Comment: If you remove all color profile information from the image, does it display the same then?

Comment: Browsers assume the image is sRGB if it's untagged.  If the colorspace of the image is actually sRGB, removing the profile should have no effect (but it does have a slight effect on Firefox if Firefox is using the "taggedOnly" (colorMode == 2).  If the image is in some other colorspace such as linear, then removing the profile or gAMA chunk will have a big effect.